# Why this count of chars in text box as you write does not update?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have implemented this function to count the available chars while the user is typing in a text box where the limit is 150 chars.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function KeyDown(sender, e) {
                // e.keyCode == 8 : backspace
                // e.keyCode == 46 : delete
                //used for detection of delete and backspace and in IE only
                if (($telerik.isIE || $telerik.isChrome || $telerik.isSafari) && (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46)) {
                    var text;

                    text = escape(sender.value);
                    var calculatedLength = unescape(text).length;
                    var lbl = document.getElementById('lblCount');
                    lbl.innerHTML = calculatedLength - 1 < 0 ? 0 : calculatedLength - 1;
                }
            }

            function KeyPress(sender, args) {
                var text;
                if ($telerik.isIE || args.get_domEvent().rawEvent.keyCode == 0 || args.get_domEvent().rawEvent.keyCode == 13) // 13 : Enter key
                {
                    text = escape(sender.get_value() + args.get_keyCharacter());
                }
                else {
                    text = escape(sender.get_value());
                }

                while (text.indexOf("%0D%0A") != -1)  // IE
                {
                    text = text.replace("%0D%0A", " ");
                }
                while (text.indexOf("%0A") != -1) {
                    text = text.replace("%0A", " ");
                }
                while (text.indexOf("%0D") != -1) {
                    text = text.replace("%0D", " ");
                }

                var calculatedLength = unescape(text).length;

                if (args.get_domEvent().rawEvent.keyCode == 8 && calculatedLength > 0) // 8 : backspace
                {
                    calculatedLength -= 1;
                }

                var lbl = document.getElementById('lblCount');
                lbl.innerHTML = calculatedLength;
            }
        </script>
```

The text box:

```
 <td class="auto-style5">
 <asp:TextBox ID="Notes1" runat="server" Height="125px" OnKeyPress="KeyPress"
  onkeydown="KeyDown(this,event)" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="370px"
  Text='<%# Bind( "Notes" ) %>'></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator9"
   runat="server" Display="dynamic" ControlToValidate="Notes1"
   ValidationExpression="^([\S\s]{0,150})$" ErrorMessage="Please enter maxium 150 characters"
   BackColor="red">
 </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
 <div id="commentstats" style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">
 <div id="Div1" style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">
  Count: <label id="lblCount"></label><br />Limit: 150
 </div>
 </div>
 </td>
```

The problem: **while I type there is no increase of chars in the counter**. If I press the key back to delete a char then the count gets updated. If I leave the page and then I go back to the page the count is correct. Do you see where is the problem causing the count not to update while typing?

Comment: Try removing `runat="server"`, and changing `nKeyPress` to `onKeyPress`.

Comment: @merlin2011 I have corrected the mistake "nKeyPressed" with "OnKeyPressed" but still has the same behavior and I cannot eliminate the runat server.

Comment: I do not have access to a `.NET` web server at the moment, but if you edit your question to include the rendered HTML on the client side, I may be able to assist more. Otherwise wait for someone who has access to `.NET`. :)

Comment: I don't get the point on using those two different events, and the number of key pressed events don't have to match with the number of characters (even controlling backspace & delete), you can select a fragment and supress it, or press a key and keep it pressed. I'd go to count the characters in the content, spite of trying to calculate it. On key up, for example, as you do it on keydown.